# Can I delete an answer I posted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I put in an answer to a question, but while I was writing/researching the answer, the question changed to include my answer, So it now looks like my answer is complete rubbish and I'm getting down votes.

How can I delete this answer?

Comment: Also, if you ALREADY got many down-votes, you can request that you rep be re-calculated after deletion, which will exclude the loss from those DV

Comment: @DVK That's interesting, I don't think I got that many down-votes.  I can manage to recoup.  But out of interest how/where/from whom(mods?) would you go about that?  Or is that a Separate question?

Comment: It's a separate Q :) But I think recalc flag is on your user page. I don't know if it's automatic or the mods have to actually do it manually.

Comment: To recalculate your reputation, go to [`/reputation`](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/reputation) and click on the button at the bottom. @DVK No, mods don't manually add up all the 10's and 5's and whatnot (:

Comment: @Gilles  - sorry, I meant that the "recalc" button goes to a mod request, and the mod kicks off the internal recalc script, to avoid people spamming the system with recalc requests that I presume are somewhat expensive

Comment: @DVK: Yeah, it is expensive. But people can't spam the system, since each user is allowed only one recalc per day. As far as I can tell, recalc is applied instantly, so I guess there isn't any batch processing either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to delete any answer you've created, as long as it hasn't been accepted by the question asker.  I've included a screen shot (complete with free-hand circle) from a site where I have lower reputation, to verify that you shouldn't need a certain reputation amount to delete your own answer:

[image]

For more information, [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean) covers this topic.

Comment: When I selected this link I was given the option to vote to delete the post, not delete it...

Comment: As the person who posted the answer, your vote is binding, much like a moderator's.  Your vote should be all that is necessary to delete it.

Comment: So is it the case that if i vote to delete my own post it's deleted?

Comment: Ah, you beat me too it, thanks.