# How to access the reputation recalculation feature

Tags: support, reputation

I recently asked this [question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/can-i-delete-an-answer-i-posted) and got some good answers, in one of the comments DVK mentions that reputation can be recalculated, and Gilles then provides a link to do just that.

When using Gilles’ link I do get to a page where I can select a recall button. I cannot, however, find a link to this link off the main site. (It might well be there, but I couldn't find on the reputation page where I assumed it would be.

So is this option freely available to everyone? If so, where is the link?

Comment: From now on, it's [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/reputation)

Comment: See also [List of unlinked pages on Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76566)

Comment: Does this feature even still exist?

Comment: @Valorum not that I know of. Wanted to try to VTC this as no repro, but apparently it's only available on main Meta...

Comment: @Jenayah - Even if it still existed, I'd be terrified to click the button in case I suddenly found I'd lost 200K

Comment: @Valorum no, I meant the close reason is only available on main Meta. The forced rep calculation [is not necessary anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123319/398063)

Comment: @Jenayah We could just close it as off-topic as if that portion doesn't exist anymore, this question isn't asking about the *"Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no link from the main site: it's a power user feature for those in the know, hidden because it's not a normal thing users need to do and recalculating reputation is a bit of an intensive process.

Nevertheless, it is freely available to registered users who know the link: the reputation recalculation button, however, only works once every 24 hours.

Answer (score 4):

Like Mark said, It's a hidden feature. Someone on MSO pointed me to this [list of other hidden features](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8211/172958):

Before you trigger a recalc, you'll want to [make sure it benefits you](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1298/3267).

Comment: I don't think it's even theoretically possible to **increase** your rep with a recalc by much, unless you have tons of majorly downvoted posts

Comment: @DVK Post an unpopular question on MSO.

Comment: Thanks for that link Kevin, will have to study that link!

Comment: @Kevin - Been there, done that, got the t-shirt :)   Though I probably lost 10x the rep on MSO compared to MSFF - that oughtta be a record!

Comment: @DVK Yeah, I just posted a question that turned out to be quite unpopular, something like -7, and I can't delete it because there's an upvoted answer...