# Reputation recalculation hurtz

Tags: support, reputation

I read [How to access the reputation recalculation feature](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1296/how-to-access-the-reputation-recalculation-feature) and thought (naively) I'll give that a try!

My rep dropped from 8187 to 7773 (-414).

Is it gone for good?

Comment: The conclusion is clear: it's gone for good. *Unlease the sock-puppets!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ha, you probably answered lots of lists and recommendation questions. I lost several hundred rep points due to that, too.

On the bright side, you'd lose that rep anyway as soon as the first scheduled rep recalc takes place, so you didn't *really* lose anything, you just made the process faster for your own account.

Comment: So how often is this done automatically?

Comment: @Tango: The team has never given any indication of the official frequency that I know of. There was once a time when scheduled recalcs were global, but then the user base grew to the point that this was computationally infeasible, so now they dribble out. Otherwise you could probably figure it our by searching for complaints on meta.SO.

Comment: @dmckee: But, in general, are we talking every month, every few months, once a year... ?

Comment: @Tango: I think the envisioned scale would be on order of monthly. When the scaling crisis hit it went many months and the howls of outrage that followed when they finally got it done were a sight to be seen.

Comment: @dmckee: SO I'll just avoid doing a recalc until I'm a few thousand above Trusted User....

Comment: By going to http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/reputation you can see what the result *would* be and know if it's "safe" or not. Right now I'd lose 33 or so...

Answer (score 5):

Yup, gone for good.

You have my deepest sympathy.

Comment: Upvoting on the assumption your second sentence is not sarcasm... :)

Comment: Upvoting for sublime sarcasm

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's gone for good - your account previously cached "wrong" reputation sum, which included rep assigned to currently-deleted Qs and As. Recalc merely calculates the "correct" sum accounting for deletions.

If it's any consolation, my first recalc on StackOverflow cost me ~1000 rep AND "super user" (10k+) priviledges since the First Big Recalc happened **2 days after I hit 10k**! Boy was I sad :)

Answer (score 0):

Ouch. I made the same mistake, but I only dropped about 50 here and on Unix and 100 on SO. Actually went up on MSO.